# Missing ) after argument list in Centos 7 VPS Server, Running normal in my windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, centos7, missing-symbols

i have an error in nodejs, it says missing ) after argument list,
it running well on visual studio code windows, but when i deploy to my Centos 7 VPS server , the error display, is it Operation System bug or else? what should i do bro?

this is the code

```
module.exports  = function(app){
const bodyParser= require('body-parser');
const database  = require('../app-config/database');
const CircularJSON = require('circular-json');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

    app.get('/api/user', async function (req, res) {
        var history = await database("SELECT * FROM history");
        res.status(200).json({
            status:true,
            info: "Berhasil Ambil Data",
            // jumlahuser : jumlahuser2.recordsets[0][0].jumlah,
            data: history
        })
    })
}
```

[image]

Comment: Best option: upgrade your Node to something not many years obsolete, so that it understands `async`/`await` syntax

Comment: solved, thanks for helping bro :D

Comment: We don't do "SOLVED" in the title here. Either post an answer and accept it, or delete the question